# Is there a way to use "randomly sample" and "if condition is satisfied" at the same time?

Tags: filtering, spss

In this dataset, people were asked questions about one or two brands, depending on what they qualified for.  Middle-aged women qualified for both brands, but one brand had a higher quota than the other, so we wound up oversampling for one of the brands.  Here's an example of the dataset:

| id | gender | brand 1 | brand 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Female | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Female | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Female | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | Male | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | Female | 1 | 1 |

I'm trying to randomly filter out some of those women for the oversampled brand.  That creates two problems:

1. I don't want women to be filtered out of both brands; I only want their answers to be removed from the oversampled brand
2. I want it to be specifically middle-aged women, not every demographic

I was able to select specifically middle-aged women by using code like this:

```
compute rnd_RAM=uniform(0,1).
compute keep_RAM=1.
if hid_AgeGender=4 & ControlvsExposed=1 & rnd_RAM<0.555555555555556 keep_RAM=0.
if hid_AgeGender=4 & ControlvsExposed=0 & rnd_RAM<0.555555555555556 keep_RAM=0.
execute.
select if keep_RAM=1.
execute.
```

I created something similar for the other brand, but actually filtering using either affected the full dataset, not just the one brand.

So what I want is for the data to look like this:

| id | gender | brand 1 | brand 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Female | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Female | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Female | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | Male | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | Female | 1 | 1 |

But instead, the filtering is giving me this:

| id | gender | brand 1 | brand 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Female | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Female | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Female | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | Male | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | Female | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Please edit your post to add a bit of example data - including expected results. If we better understand the structure of your data and what you want to do with it we can certainly help.